# systemd mount only mounts on boot, fails to remount afterwards

Tags: mount, systemd

I have created a mount, `mnt-stoneshare.mount`, placed in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=StoneOS Storage Mount

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/62721034-29ee-4894-a19e-905bcbb20c7c
Where=/mnt/stoneshare

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

The file is being generated automatically by an installer of a software that I'm working on.

Apparently, right after generation (the system is running), if I attempt to start the mount by `systemctl start /mnt/stoneshare` or the equivalent `systemctl start mnt-stoneshare.mount`, the unit does not fail, but the mounting does not happen. Checking `journalctl`, there is some weirdness:

```
Nov 22 20:28:12 stone-development-arch systemd[367]: Unmounted /mnt/stoneshare.
Nov 22 20:28:12 stone-development-arch systemd[367]: Unmounting /mnt/stoneshare...
Nov 22 20:28:12 stone-development-arch systemd[367]: Unit mnt-stoneshare.mount is bound to inactive service. Stopping, too.
Nov 22 20:28:12 stone-development-arch kernel: EXT4-fs (md127): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

First off, it says that it's mounted (therefore, I assume the exit code being 0 on `mount`), but immediately after, it's being unmounted.

And checking `systemctl status /mnt/stoneshare`, there are no errors either:

```
[root@stone-development-arch StoneOS.RaidProcess]# systemctl status /mnt/stoneshare/
● mnt-stoneshare.mount - StoneOS Storage Mount
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-stoneshare.mount; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2014-11-22 20:28:12 EET; 4min 11s ago
    Where: /mnt/stoneshare
     What: /dev/disk/by-uuid/62721034-29ee-4894-a19e-905bcbb20c7c
  Process: 855 ExecMount=/bin/mount -n /dev/disk/by-uuid/62721034-29ee-4894-a19e-905bcbb20c7c /mnt/stoneshare -t auto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

My installer also enables (`systemctl enable /mnt/stoneshare`) after the attempt to start the unit. If I reboot the system, the device gets mounted properly. If I am to unmount (by stopping the unit) and attempt to remount (by starting the unit) I get the same errors.

I assume that the problem relies in the configuration of my Unit, yet, being a `systemd` newbie I cannot seem to find the solution.

I have read through [the issue here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/9/26/903), but doesn't seem to be the case.
Also, I walked through [this bug on RedHats'](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1159987) but the UUID's and everything else is correct, plus, the mounting happens if it's performed on boot. Have went through [other](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=lv&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwopfel.de%2F2014%2F09%2Fautomatischer-umount-durch-systemd%2F&edit-text=&act=url) [posts](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1159648) also, to no avail.

What is causing the mount to be immediately unmounted if performed manually?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my, what a fail, I had leftovers from previous tests in `/etc/systemd/user` that conflicted.

Apparently, when running systemd units from logged in users context, it will favor `/etc/systemd/user` directory - that's why it failed on manual mounts, but worked on boot.

Removing the unit from user namespace, fixed the issue for manual mounts too.